# Record set not updatable

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am at a loss as to why I am getting a run time error message saying that the record set is not updatable for a simple table which I created and sourced in a new form not dependent on anything else.  Is it possible the database settings have somehow changed causing me this strange issue. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Some more details would be needed. 
Anyway, how are you trying to modify the recordset? Via VBA?
I suggest some things you can try:

- Open form properties --> Data tab and check that Allow modifications is set to Yes as far as Allow Additions and so on
  1) You are trying to access the record before updating
  2) In VBA you didn't invoke the .Edit method before trying to modify the record.
  3) The form has a query as record source and the query is not updatable

The case 3) is the most complex of the three. It can be due, for example, to:
  - Presence of total clauses like GROUP BY, COUNT, SUM that means that a record represents a set
  - A calculated field that can't be updated
  - Lack of permission to modify the table / query